# How to Automatic minify Html files in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, minify, bundling-and-minification

Visual Studio Minifier dosent Automatic minify Html files in my project.[link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40)
For the first time we are manually minify Field works,but it's not work in change html.

How do I set up for automatic minify in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found A Visual Studio 2015 extension to minify html files upon save.I Use this extension for now. To release a new Version.
https://github.com/desmati/MinifyOnSave